# Pasting new records to a Bound DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource

Apologies if this has already been asked. If so, I am unable to find a simple solution. I am trying to allow a user to copy/paste multiple records in a DataGridView (the in memory copy of the data, to be saved later when the user clicks the save button) and cannot find anything that works. It probably is because there is something I do not understand about all of this.

I set up a standard edit form with Visual Studio's drag/table into a form, so it's using a BindingSource control and all the other controls that come with doing that. It works just fine when manually entering something in the new row one by one, so it seems to be set up correctly, but when it comes to adding a record (or multiples) using code, nothing seems to work.

I tried a few things as outline in the code below. Could someone please at least steer me in the right direction? It cannot be that difficult to paste multiple records.

I run this when the user presses Control-V (the clipboard correctly holds the delimited strings):

```
Private Sub PasteClipboard()
    If Clipboard.ContainsText Then
        Dim sLines() As String = Clipboard.GetText.Split(vbCrLf)
        For Each sLine As String In sLines
            Dim Items() As String = sLine.Split(vbTab)

            Dim drv As DataRowView = AdjustmentsBindingSource.AddNew()
            drv.Item(1) = Items(0)
            drv.Item(2) = Items(1)
            drv.Item(3) = Items(2)
            drv.Item(4) = Items(3)
'Error on next line : Cannot add external objects to this list.
            AdjustmentsBindingSource.Add(drv)

        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

(the bindingsource is bound to a dataadapter, which is bound to a table in an mdb file, if that helps understand)

I adjusted the inner part of the code to this:

```
            If (RowHasData(Items)) Then
                Dim drv As DataRowView = AdjustmentsBindingSource.AddNew()
                drv.Item("FontName") = Items(0)
                drv.Item("FontSize") = Items(1)
                drv.Item("LetterCombo") = Items(2)
                drv.Item("Adjustment") = Items(3)
                drv.Item("HorV") = Items(4)
            End If
```

It kinda works, but it also adds a blank row before the 2 new rows. Not sure where that is coming from, as I have even included your `RowHasData()` routine...

[image]

Comment: You need to explain what actually happens when you execute the code you have.

Comment: Thanks. I updated it trying to make it more clear. Is that enough information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that “attemp3” SHOULD work, however, it is unclear “what” the `AdjustmentsBindingSource’s` `DataSource` is. Is it a `List<T>` or `DataTable`?

If I set the `BinngSource.DataSource` to a `DataTable`, then attempt 3 appears to work. Below is an example that worked.

```
Private Sub PasteClipboard2()
    If Clipboard.ContainsText Then
        Dim sLines() As String = Clipboard.GetText.Split(vbCrLf)
        For Each sLine As String In sLines
            Dim Items() As String = sLine.Split(vbTab)
            If (RowHasData(Items)) Then
                Dim drv As DataRowView = AdjustmentsBindingSource.AddNew()
                drv.Item("FontName") = Items(0)
                drv.Item("FontSize") = Items(1)
                drv.Item("LetterCombo") = Items(2)
                drv.Item("Adjustment") = Items(3)
                drv.Item("HorV") = Items(4)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This appears to work in my tests. I added a small function (RowHasData) to avoid malformed strings causing problems. It simply checks the size (at least 5 items) and also checks to make sure a row actually has “some” data. If a row is just empty strings, then it is ignored.

```
Private Function RowHasData(items As String())
    If (items.Count >= 5) Then
        For Each item In items
            If (item <> "") Then Return True
        Next
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

I am guessing it would be just as easy to add the new rows “directly” to the `BindingSource`’s `DataSource.` In the example below, the code is adding the row “directly” to the `DataTable` that is used as a `DataSource` to the `BindingSource.` I am confident you could do the same thing with a `List<T>` by simply adding a new object to the list. Below is a complete example using a `BindingSource` and a `DataTable`. This simply adds the rows to the bottom of the table.

```
Dim gridTable1 As DataTable

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PasteClipboard()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    gridTable1 = GetTable()
    FillTable(gridTable1)
    AdjustmentsBindingSource.DataSource = gridTable1
    AdjustmentsDataGridView.DataSource = AdjustmentsBindingSource
End Sub

Private Function GetTable() As DataTable
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("FontName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("FontSize", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("LetterCombo", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Adjustment", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("HorV", GetType(String))
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub FillTable(dt As DataTable)
    For index = 1 To 10
        dt.Rows.Add("Name_" + index.ToString(), "Size_" + index.ToString(), "Combo_" + index.ToString(), "Adjust_" + index.ToString(), "HorV_" + index.ToString())
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PasteClipboard()
    If Clipboard.ContainsText Then
        Dim sLines() As String = Clipboard.GetText.Split(vbCrLf)
        Try
            Dim dataRow As DataRow
            For Each sLine As String In sLines
                Dim Items() As String = sLine.Split(vbTab)
                If (RowHasData(Items)) Then
                    dataRow = gridTable1.NewRow()
                    dataRow("FontName") = Items(0)
                    dataRow("FontSize") = Items(1)
                    dataRow("LetterCombo") = Items(2)
                    dataRow("Adjustment") = Items(3)
                    dataRow("HorV") = Items(4)
                    gridTable1.Rows.Add(dataRow)
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Function RowHasData(items As String())
    If (items.Count >= 5) Then
        For Each item In items
            If (item <> "") Then Return True
        Next
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Hope the code helps…

Last but important, I am only guessing that you may have not “TESTED” the different ways users can “SELECT” data and “how” other applications “copy” that selected data. My previous tests using the WIN-OS “Clipboard” can sometimes give unexpected results. Example, if the user selects multiple items using the ”Ctrl” key to “ADD” to the selection, extra rows appeared in the Clipboard if the selection was not contiguous. My important point is that using the OS clipboard is quirky IMHO. I recommend LOTS of testing on the “different” ways the user can select the data. If this is not an issue then the code above should work.

Comment: I updated the question again if you have the time to look at it. It's adding an extra blank row for some reason. I'm trying not to add too much extra/new things in an effort to keep it simple enough for me to understand.

Comment: The blank row appears only if I instinctively highlight the new row right before pasting, so I guess i just need to figure out why that happens and how to prevent it.

Comment: As I commented at the end, I had the same `vblf` (linefeed) in one of the fields for empty strings DEPENDING on how I “selected” the text. I was simply copying from another grid and also from an Excel spreadsheet. I got different results on each, hence the `RowHasData` method. I am confident if you jump down this rabbit hole, you will do a lot more checking as you test the OS clipboard.

Comment: This is one reason I was commenting from the perspective of using the OS’s “Clipboard.” You are pretty much going to have to follow what IT wants to do. As seen, depending on “how” the user selects the data OR how another application handles the “copy” command to the OS, can have different results. Also, I would think that there would have to be a ton of checking since the user can basically COPY anything. IF the user is coping from another `DataGridView`, then I suggest using the grids `SelectedRows` collection to eliminate a lot of checking that will be needed using the OS clipboard.

Comment: I guess I was just trying to keep it simple and have it act like Excel, as that is what the users are used to dealing with. - Copying 4 existing rows and adjusting a few of the results. Is there a simple way to do that? Because all those extra things in your long version answer just kinda make my head swim as a new-ish .NET developer.

Comment: I sympathize with you. I once though it should be fairly easy to do this, however, the bottleneck is dealing with the OS clipboard which is quirky IMHO. I would try and avoid using the OS clipboard because of this and the fact that the user can select data in different ways.

Comment: Going out on a limb, if the user is copying from Excel, could you not use your application to open the Excel file, the user selects some cells in Excel, then clicks a button on your application to copy the selected cells to the grid? Just a thought. This avoids using the OS clipboard and should be easier to validate if the selection fits the grid and has valid data.

Comment: Let me know and I will delete the answer since it doesn’t really help.

Comment: It could help someone else tho, I say leave it. Maybe i'll use it as reference for some other solution in the near future... Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I say go for it, if you will only be “copying” from Excel, then the `RowHasData` method will need a lot more work and consistency may be an issue however, in the end it should work. I just don’t have the patience to figure out the quirks in the OS copy. Good Luck!